# Is out there any tutorial on how to unzip a zip file with folders and files inside into some dir and pack them back via MiniZip?

Tags: c++, c, zip, zlib

Is out there any C/C++ tutorial on how to unzip a zip file with folders and files inside into some dir and pack them back via  MiniZip?

Answer (score 0):

There is no tutorial that shows exactly that. There is however two examples included in the MiniZip source code. One is miniunz.c which shows how to use the library to unzip files and folders. And the other is minizip.c which shows how to use the library to zip files and folders.